# Monitor with 'glossy' screen?

Tags: display

I was wondering if there was any particular name for monitors that have a 'glossy' finish/layer of glass/perspex/whatever over the screen? I'm looking to buy a monitor and like the extra depth that they add (at least for my eyes), so want to make sure I get one of this specifically. It isn't entirely obvious in a lot of product photos.

Does anyone know if they have any imparticular name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhm, yeah, glossy is actually the name they use in product descriptions.
It's pretty safe to assume that it's glossy if unspecified. They usually sell better because of said "depth".

Comment: Assume it's glossy if unspecified? You sure? I thought matte ones were still more common... I should probably just make sure it either says matte or glossy before enquiring. Thanks for clarifying that there's no fancy term for them though, 'glossy' it is. :)

Comment: Well the exception would be the big monitors and really small laptops where eye fatigue is more of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes glossy is the name that they use to describe that attribute. However, I wouldn't go so far as to say that it is so standard you can just buy any monitor, even if it doesn't specify, and it will be glossy. In fact, most LCD monitors are not glossy, out of all the monitors on newegg I only found a few that matched that description.

If it is important to you that the screen be glossy, I would suggest you buy one with "glossy" in the product description, or contact the manufacturer to make sure before purchasing.